# org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName Could not find or load main class

Tags: hadoop

When i run the hadoop command, getting error as below. But it worked fine before.

```
[hadoop@testing-server hadoop]$ bin/hadoop namenode -format

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
```

Comment: This is because either jar files not available or not set in the classpath.

Comment: got it it was error due to deletion of jar files

Comment: yes after restore jar files its resolved.

Comment: Ok I will post the answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because either jar files not available (deleted) or the jar location not set in the classpath.

Make sure all jar files available in the hadoop/share location.